Is the characteristic-Cauchy problem in General Relativity well-posed?
It is known that the spacelike-characteristic Cauchy problem is well-posed when the intersection surface is a "corner" (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.07355). I am trying to figure out whether something similar is true in the smooth case, i.e. when the spacelike hypersurface tends smoothly to the null ones (see the image below).

I know the classic work by Hormander (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123690901299) where the Cauchy problem is solved on non-timelike hypersurfaces. The problem here is that, in this paper, $u$ is a function, so I don't really know if this can be applied to a coupled system like the Einstein equations, to a vector field, etc. If yes, then I guess the Cauchy problem on the RHS of the figure would be well-posed as well.
Does anyone know a result on this matter?
